# Coherence and $g^{(2)}$

Tags: photons, quantum-optics, coherence

We talk about how coherent light has a $g^{(2)}(\tau)=1$ and thermal light has $g^{(2)}(0)=2$. However, we can talk about the coherence length of a thermal source if we put it through a very narrow filter and say it has some coherence length. I guess my question is: does this coherence length relate to $g^{(1)}$ rather than $g^{(2)}$? Maybe I'm getting mixed up with the definition of a coherent source.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be correct, thermal light has a coherence length even if it's not spectrally narrow. The coherence length would just be very short.

In [Loudon – The quantum theory of light (2000)](https://books.google.de/books/about/The_Quantum_Theory_of_Light.html) chapter 3.1 the coherence time is defined by the spectral width of the light. Therefore, by the [Wiener-Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) it is related to $g^{(1)}$. But for thermal light the [Siegert relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_light_scattering#Description:~:text=The%20Siegert%20equation%20relates%20the%20second%2Dorder,first%2Dorder%20autocorrelation%20function%20g1(q%3B%CF%84)%20as%20follows%3A) holds, which states $g^{(2)} (\tau) = 1 + \left( g^{(1)} (\tau) \right)^2$.

Comment: Thank you, makes more sense now.